# What azure/aws services to use to be able to subscribe to particular IoT device

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, azure-eventhub, azure-iot-hub, aws-iot

Say I have 1000 IoT devices. Each device sends telemetry data to the Azure cloud each second. There is mobile app which displays that telemetry data. Mobile user can see data from specific IoT device only, based on his login. It's not an issue to receive all those d2c messages in the cloud, for example with Event Hubs (initially i wanted to use IoT Hub, but it's pretty expensive with huge amount of messages). It's also clear how to get general event stream (for example, by listening to events endpoint in IoT hub). However, this stream gives all messages, from all devices. Receiving all messages in mobile app and filtering them there does not look like right choice. How can I subscribe to events from specific IoT device only? Can I do this with Event Hubs and/or IoT Hub only, or do I need to utilize other Azure services? If yes, what will be the most cheap solution.

Update:
Original question was just about Azure. But is it possible to achieve what I need with AWS without requiring adding multiple parts to the system. Is [Message Broker for AWS IoT](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-message-broker.html) what I need here (as I understood, this is built in functionality of AWS IoT Core)?

Comment: have a look at the solution described in the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48688749/process-azure-iot-hub-events-from-a-single-device-only/48724497#48724497

Comment: Can that be accomplished with Event Hubs and Event Grid. The price for Event Hubs is significantly lower than for IoT Hub. Same with Functions - it's costly when you are processing millions of events.

Comment: Yes, the integration (push) stack is between the streaming model to the event-driven model (Azure IoT Hub/Event Hub and Event Grid). Based on your telemetry sources such as telemetry devices, I do recommend to use an Azure IoT Hub as a IoT Gateway for your devices to the cloud streaming pipeline, see differences to the Event Hubs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-compare-event-hubs

Comment: IoT Hub might be a better solution. But the cost when you have millions of events is at least 10 times higher then with Event Hubs.

Comment: The Azure IoT Hub is a gateway for your IoT devices with a comprehensive platform for scalability, device management, security and communication in the manner of IoT-specific features. In other words, the Azure IoT Hub = Azure Event Hub + IoT-specific features. If your scenario doesn't need the IoT-specific features, than the Event Hub is your choice.